# Cloning a JS TreeModel tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, treemodel

I need to clone a tree I made using [TreeModel.js](http://jnuno.com/tree-model-js/).
What I exactly need to do is duplicating it, make changes to it and check if the number of nodes decreased. If it did, revert to the original tree. Here's a small example of what I do so far to duplicate it, which is not correct:

```
var tree = new TreeModel();
var root = tree.parse({
    id: 0,
    name: "Root",
    children: [{id: 1, name: "1", children: []},{id: 2, name: "2", children: []}]
});

console.log(root)
var dup = tree.parse(root)
console.log(dup)
```

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvzb9vd2/1/). You'll see the difference between the trees by looking at the console:

```
Node {config: Object, model: Object, children: Array[2], isRoot: function, hasChildren: function…}
Node {config: Object, model: Node, children: Array[2], isRoot: function, hasChildren: function…}
```

Is there any way to properly clone such a structure? I looked for cloning JS object but still, I can't find a way for cloning this object exactly (such as the prototypes of properties like the model...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deep clone the model of the first tree and parse it again to get a second tree.

Taking on your example:

```
function deepCopy(obj) {
    // You can also use the jquery extend method here
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}

var dup = tree.parse(deepCopy(root.model));
```

Important: If you do not deep clone the model, and just parse it again, you'll end up with the same underlying model shared by both trees which will certainly cause inconsistencies.

Comment: You're the one who wrote this library right? Then, is there a difference with simply doing: `tree.parse(root.model);`?

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much for both the library and this answer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I finally came to a solution that may help anyone with the same problem:

```
var tree = new TreeModel();
var root = tree.parse({
    id: 0,
    name: "Root",
    children: [{id: 1, name: "1", children: []},{id: 2, name: "2", children: []}]
});

console.log(root)
var dup = tree.parse(root.model)
console.log(dup)
```

The `parse` function takes a model as parameter and the model of root seems to work fine.

EDIT: this solution may bring inconsistencies since the 2 trees are based on the same model. JNS's solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying a jQuery deep copy?

```
var dup = jQuery.extend(true, {}, tree)
```

I tried your fiddle but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Did you check the console? That's where I can check the structure.
Yes, I tried a deep copy but still, I can't get an exact replica. Have a look at the console in this updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvzb9vd2/5/

Comment: Yeah, I realized only too late that you were not writing in the "log" div but on the console. And I agree, that's not the same object really.

Comment: I think I found this solution: var dup2 = tree.parse(root.model)

*Edit: ok , you found it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mrluc/owl-deepcopy  this worked for me.

`newTree = deepCopy(tree)`