# Save the edited tree as a json object in the original format

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, treemodel

```
let data = {
"name": "root",
"children": [{
    "name": "analytics",
    "children": [{
        "name": "cluster",
        "children": [{
            "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
            "size": 3938
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "graph",
        "children": [{
            "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
            "size": 3534
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "optimization",
        "children": [{
            "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
            "size": 7074
        }]
    }]
}]
};

let child1 = {
"name": "flex",
"children": [{
    "name": "FlareVis",
    "size": 4116
}]
};

let tree = new TreeModel();
let root = tree.parse(data);
//# Add a child
let tempChild1 = tree.parse(child1);
//# Add a child at a given index
root.addChildAtIndex(tempChild1, 0);
console.log(root);
```

Using this library: http://jnuno.com/tree-model-js/ for tree manipulation.
So, how is it possible to get the data back from the library in the original format after addition or deletion.

```
After the above operation, how can I get back this modified object from the library?
   data = {
"name": "root",
"children": [{
    "name": "analytics",
    "children": [{
        "name": "cluster",
        "children": [{
            "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
            "size": 3938
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "graph",
        "children": [{
            "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
            "size": 3534
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "optimization",
        "children": [{
            "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
            "size": 7074
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "name": "flex",
    "children": [{
        "name": "FlareVis",
        "size": 4116
    }]
}]
}
```

Is there a way the library can do this, or is there an efficient way to convert it back to desired format, that is the original format.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify(root.model);
```

Solves my problem, found the answer at 
[Transforming a tree back to JSON using tree-model-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193137/transforming-a-tree-back-to-json-using-tree-model-js)
and
[Cloning a JS TreeModel tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27481417/cloning-a-js-treemodel-tree)

Thank you so much.